# changing the .htaccess file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I was trying to use `permalink feature` of `WordPress` on my `localhost` so I just made copy the code which was `generated by WordPress` when I clicked on `post name from Common Settings`. I saved that generated code in my localhost where the `wordpress index.php` file was stored in the name of `.htaccess` and now when I am going to visit the page, url bar of the `browser is showing the full address of the post` but the `post can not be seen on the browser`.Only the `404 Not Found error is comming`. Can someone tell me what is the wrong part here?

Answer (score 12):

You should let wordpress write this file for your localhost server.

You cannot simply copy `.htaccess` from another server and expect it will work, you have to modify it to reflect your server conf.

You should modify `RewriteBase` and the last `RewriteRule`, e.g. for `http://localhost/wordpress` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @MadanBhandari in the .htaccess file as suggested in the sentence bellow.

Comment: Thanks, worked as expected. But in case you're hosted your website on windows localhost you only need to change the <code>/wordpress/</code> to your actual directory name. Thanks